# How to make sure the generated random number is not equal to the next generated number?

Tags: ios, swift

I am generating a random number (only 0-2) in swift each time a button is pressed. But I don't want it to generate the same number twice in a row.
This is what I did but it's not working.

```
var currentNumber:Int = 5
var randomNumber:Int = 0

do {
    randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(3)))
} while randomNumber == currentNumber

currentNumber = randomNumber
```

Comment: I ran your code in a playground and it worked perfectly, with Xcode telling me to change "do" to "repeat"

Comment: Is there a difference between do and repeat?

Comment: Apple's Swift book: "The repeat-while loop in Swift is analogous to a do-while loop in other languages."

Comment: Note `do-while` was used for Swift 1.0 through Swift 1.2, then it became `repeat-while` in Swift 2.0 because `do` was repurposed for the new `do-try-catch` error handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make `randomNumber` a property of your `ViewController` so that it is remembered between button presses.  Each time, there are only 2 valid random numbers, so generate a number in the range `0` to `1` and then change it to `2` if it matches your previous number:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    // Give randomNumber an initial value
    var randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(3)))

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(button: UIButton) {
        let currentNumber = randomNumber
        randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(2)))
        if currentNumber == randomNumber {
            randomNumber = 2
        }
    }
}
```

This has the advantage of only needing 1 random number each button press.

Comment: Shouldn't the code continue to generate a random number so that if the first number is 0, both 1 and 2 have an equal chance to be the second number, instead of defaulting to 2?

Comment: that's a good way, but why wouldn't the `randomNumber` be remembered in my code?

Comment: No.  There are only 2 acceptable random numbers each time.  If the first number is 0, then when the second number is generated (a 0 or a 1), the 0 will become the 2.

Comment: It wasn't clear by your code what is in the body of the button function and what is part of the `ViewController`.  If your code is all in the body of the button function, then `currentNumber` and `randomNumber` get created anew each time the button is pressed, so nothing is remembered between button presses.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you prevent the same number from appearing twice in a row, your sequence is no longer random / pseudorandom.  However, if you must, you can compare the newest value to the previous and retry until they differ.

Comment: The do/while loop always runs once before checking the conditional. In this case, he picks a random number, then checks it against the previous number, and executes the do statement again if it is.

Comment: I was going to say what shades said. And also why would preventing the same number from appearing twice in a row wouldn't make it a random?

Comment: Thanks!!! Misread that one!!! It's not random in a theoretical sense... Flipping a coin you can have an arbitrary number of tails in a row....